# servlet to access the MySql data

Tags: mysql

I'm using a servlet to access the MySQL data. I already have the code for sending the file from the servlet to the response.

What I don't know is how I'm supossed to catch it with javascript, because I'm not making this call by submit. I don't want to reload the hole page.

I tried making a window.open to the servlet, sending all the params by URL, but it only opens a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to look into AJAX. jquery has some stuff to make that easier. I have done some ajax, but that was jquery-less so it is probably better if I point you in the right direction rather than post reams of code.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/ajax-jquery

Your servlet response type needs to be:

```
response.setContentType("text/xml");
```

Hope this helps.